# PowerPoint files as video on web page

Tags: video, video-streaming, powerpoint, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

One of client requires to share and view the .PPT(Microsoft PowerPoint Slides) files online as video, on his web application.In our company live streaming a programs in online. one of my client ask the ppt file also live streaming in a online web page. Is there any options to to streaming that ppt files in a online web page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need animations you could save all slides as images on the file system and then use an API to edit videos and create a video from the images.